# How can I add my map to my personal blog?

Tags: html, ruby

I have been able to deploy the map on the web, so I can access the html file and all the javascript together, but can I put it on my personal website? My blog has been deployed using Ruby on Rails

Comment: How did you put your map on the web? what have you tried so far? what seems not to be working?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: I have not tried to do any yet, that's why I am asking here. I have gone through the documentation on this link https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html but being just a page that I can access I was wondering how could I add it as a page, or as part of a page of my personal blog, so I can show my map.

Comment: please take the [tour] and look at what I wrote above

Comment: Thanks for your help